# CORBA omniorb C++ multiple servants

Tags: c++, linux, p2p, corba, omniorb

Hi everybody i'm new in CORBA C++, I read a tutorial for how to install CORBA on linux, its working and the code compiles fine, i wanna execute more than one server instance because i wanna create a peer-to-peer. for example when i create one server instance and multiple client instances works fine, but when i tried to execute two or more server instances in order to receiving messages from the clients only the last server instance receive the messages, please can anyone help me?

Here is my code for server and client

***server.cpp***

```
#include "MyExampleInterface_impl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <CORBA.h>
#include <Naming.hh>

/** Server name, clients needs to know this name */
#define SERVER_NAME     "MyServerName"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
cerr << "CORBA SERVER RUNNING..." << endl;
try {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize CORBA ORB
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CORBA::ORB_ptr orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize POA: Get reference to root POA
    //
    // Servant must register with POA in order to be made available for client
    // Get reference to the RootPOA.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    CORBA::Object_var poa_obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");
    PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow(poa_obj);
    PortableServer::POAManager_var manager = poa->the_POAManager();

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create service
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MyExampleInterface_impl * service = new MyExampleInterface_impl;
    cerr << "ya se creo el servicio procediendo a crear instancia" << endl;
    try {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Bind object to name service as defined by directive InitRef
        // and identifier "NameService" in config file omniORB.cfg.
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CORBA::Object_var ns_obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        if (!CORBA::is_nil(ns_obj)) {
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Narrow this to the naming context
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CosNaming::NamingContext_ptr nc = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(ns_obj);

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Bind to CORBA name service. Same name to be requested by client.
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CosNaming::Name name;
            name.length(1);
            name[0].id = CORBA::string_dup(SERVER_NAME);
            name[0].kind = CORBA::string_dup("");
            nc->rebind(name, service->_this());

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Intizialization ready, server runs
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------              
            cout << argv[0] << " C++ (omniORB) server '" << SERVER_NAME << "' is running .." << endl;
        }
    } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound &) {
        cerr << "Caught CORBA exception: not found" << endl;
    } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::InvalidName &) {
        cerr << "Caught CORBA exception: invalid name" << endl;
    } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::CannotProceed &) {
        cerr << "Caught CORBA exception: cannot proceed" << endl;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Activate the POA manager
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    manager->activate();
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Accept requests from clients
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
cerr << "aceptando peticiones de cliente con run()" << endl;
    orb->run();
cerr << "hecho ahora esperando..." << endl;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Clean up
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //delete service;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Destroy ORB
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    orb->destroy();

} catch (CORBA::UNKNOWN) {
    cerr << "Caught CORBA exception: unknown exception" << endl;
} catch (CORBA::SystemException &) {
    cerr << "Caught CORBA exception: system exception" << endl;
}
```

}

***client.cpp***

```
#include "example.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <CORBA.h>
#include <Naming.hh>

/** Name is defined in the server.cpp */
#define SERVER_NAME     "MyServerName"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    try {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Initialize ORB object.
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CORBA::ORB_ptr orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Resolve service
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ExampleInterface_ptr service_server = 0;

        try {

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Bind ORB object to name service object.
            // (Reference to Name service root context.)
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CORBA::Object_var ns_obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");

            if (!CORBA::is_nil(ns_obj)) {
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Bind ORB object to name service object.
                // (Reference to Name service root context.)
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CosNaming::NamingContext_ptr nc = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(ns_obj);

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // The "name text" put forth by CORBA server in name service.
                // This same name ("MyServerName") is used by the CORBA server when
                // binding to the name server (CosNaming::Name).
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CosNaming::Name name;
                name.length(1);
                name[0].id = CORBA::string_dup(SERVER_NAME);
                name[0].kind = CORBA::string_dup("");

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Resolve "name text" identifier to an object reference.
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CORBA::Object_ptr obj = nc->resolve(name);

                if (!CORBA::is_nil(obj)) {
                    service_server = ExampleInterface::_narrow(obj);
                }
            }
        } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound &) {
            cerr << "Caught corba not found" << endl;
        } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::InvalidName &) {
            cerr << "Caught corba invalid name" << endl;
        } catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::CannotProceed &) {
            cerr << "Caught corba cannot proceed" << endl;
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Do stuff
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (!CORBA::is_nil(service_server)) {
            char * server = service_server->send_message("Message from C++ (omniORB) client");
            cout << "response from Server: " << server << endl;
            CORBA::string_free(server);
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Destroy OBR
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        orb->destroy();

    } catch (CORBA::UNKNOWN) {
        cerr << "Caught CORBA exception: unknown exception" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using CORBA? I spent a couple of years developing in it for a living, and nothing would ever persuade me to go back to  it.

Comment: yes it's for a school final project so I don't have choice :(
and honestly I'm lost in CORBA

Comment: You need to post the terms of your assignment. What you're attempting doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: I need to do a P2P network, so the client and server eventually will be mixed into one entity, and this entity must be capable to connect with other entitys in order to make a P2P network, CORBA is confusing for me, I prefer to use "sockets" but the teacher does'nt allow it

Comment: That doesn't  explain why you're binding two servers to the same naming service with the same name.

Comment: I don't wanna bind two servers with the same naming service, do you know how it works a Peer from a P2P?, it's like a morphic object that make both actions (server and client) as required.

Answer (score 0):

The Naming Service is like a telephone book, you store an object reference using a known name. Currently you "MyServerName" in your code and there can only be one server registered with it. Starting a second server will update the Naming Service to only use the second server, all new clients will use that from that point.

You could register each server in the Naming Service with an unique name and let the client decide which server to use.

Comment: ok I got it, but it's possible for one client connect with multiple servers at the same time? because for this project I need to do a P2P network, so the client and server eventually will be mixed into one entity, and this entity must be capable to connecte with other entitys.

Comment: Yes, a client can connect to multiple servers, you need to register each server with an unique id in the naming service and the client has to retrieve multiple ones from the naming service.

Comment: can I do a CORBA Server without register a Naming Service? is mandatory register a NamingService?

Comment: No, it is not mandatory, in fact I prefer not to use it, it is a single point of failure. When you know where the server runs and on which port using the IORTable at the server side the client can construct an object reference in code and use it.